# AWS SQS FIFO ApproximateNumberOfMessages

Tags: amazon-web-services, queue, amazon-sqs, fifo

I have 2 FIFO queues (with priority).
I need to process only one message at a time.
I can't just get messages from high queue - if any - process, if noone - get from low queue. I need to understant, if there are any messages in flight.
I need to check if there are any messages in flight and from which queue to check.
So i load ApproximateNumberOfMessages and ApproximateNumberOfMessagesNotVisible for each queue and analyze them.

This is my part of code

```
            if (highPriorityQueueState.MessagesInFlight || lowPriorityQueueState.MessagesInFlight) {
            return Promise.resolve();
        }

        if (highPriorityQueueState.MessagesInQueue) {
            return _receiveMessageFromQueue(highPriorityQueueUrl);
        }

        if (lowPriorityQueueState.MessagesInQueue) {
            return _receiveMessageFromQueue(lowPriorityQueueUrl);
        }

        return Promise.resolve();
```

The Question is: can i rely on this logic? The Amazon Documentation ( http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-resources-required-process-messages.html ) says that for FIFO queues, these values are exact. But i'm not sure. Maybe anyone know how to process 2 queues with only exactly one message in flight?

Comment: This solution seems problematic for a different reason than you might anticipate, and the specific nature of the problem will vary depending on whether you have exactly 1 consumer, or more than one.

Comment: I think a better architecture pattern in your code would to just poll the queue for messages, if none in priority queue to low queue, rinse and repeat.